# PHP / MYSQL Date Calculations for automated billing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sending 'reminder' messages every 30 days, and was wondering how to calculate the time based on the timestamp I placed on the originating users signup date.

I will have a cron job run every day to query and send the messages, but I am unsure how to query the date so it will select the appropriate accounts each day and send the messages.

Any sure fire ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the query below should fit. If you can give me any more details on what / how you wish to query I can make this SQL more specific. This current query selects users whose `signup_date` was 30 or more days ago:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_ADD(signup_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= NOW()
```

For further information:

- [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [Some notes on `INTERVAL` usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to return the difference between then and `NOW()` in days.